# Teletrasporation step in Page Rank

Tags: graph-theory, page-rank

I'm reading some definition of page rank, in particular how page rank work on the web graph.

I'm a little bit confused about the definition of the teletransportation step.

How I understand this phase is if we have a Graph G with size N, the probability to be in each node is equally distributed so the probability is $\frac{1}{N}$.

So, if I got the point, the teletrasportation step on the rank function is the $\frac{1}{N}$ positioned in the last part of the formula, right?

$rank(i) = \alpha \cdot \sum_{j \in B(i)}{
                \frac{rank(j)}{B(j)} + (1 - \alpha) \cdot \frac{1}{N}
            }$

Comment: Please take a look at [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/947379) to see how to format math on this site.

Comment: I can *guess* at what you mean by "teletransportation step" just from basic familiarity with the PageRank algorithm, but you might actually be the first to use that terminology for PageRank - at least, I haven't found any other sources - so it's not 100% clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen more often the word *teleportation*.

The idea is to modify a bit the initial graph/matrix in order to be able to apply Perron-Frobenius theorem.

Usually, starting from the random walk matrix $H_{i,j} = \frac{1}{d^+(i)}  \text{ if $i$ is connected to $j$}$;   the first step is to get rid of the dead-ends by setting $S_{i,j} = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{d^+(i)}  \text{ if $i$ is connected to $j$ and }{d^+(i)} >0   \\ {\frac{1}{n} \text{ otherwise }}\end{cases}  $.

With this you get a *stochastic* matrix. Then you force the matrix to be *aperiodic* by adding a teleportation component $G = \alpha S + (1-\alpha)\frac{1}{n} J$ ($J$ is the all-one matrix). Doing so you get a stochastic aperiodic matrix and you can apply Perron Theorem.

I find [this survey](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Ecslui/CMSC5734/ALangville_Survey.pdf) quite nice and helpful.

Comment: can you define whare are the new variable that you point out? like $d^+$

Comment: $d^+(i)$ is the out-degree (that is, the number of edges going out of vertex $i$.
Btw, $\alpha$ should be tuned: small $\alpha$ means fast convergence but being further away from the initial model. It seems Google used (in early version) $\alpha \approx .85$.